# How to make list require at list 1 value with XSD?

Tags: xml, xsd

How can i ensure that a list in an xml doc has atleast one value from the allowed types?

I have tried using minlength = 1 but this has not worked:

```
  <xs:simpleType name="FeatureOption">
    <xs:list>
      <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
          <xs:minLength value="1"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="F0"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="F0A"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="F0B"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="F0C"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="F1"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="F2"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="F2A"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="F3"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="F3A"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="F3B"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="F3C"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="DataOnly"/>
        </xs:restriction>
      </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:list>
  </xs:simpleType>
```

I have also tried this:

```
<xs:element name="Feature" type="FeatureOption" nillable="false" minOccurs="1"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution should be

```
<xs:simpleType name="FeatureOptionType">
    <xs:restriction base="FeatureOption">
        <xs:minLength value="1"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:simpleType name="FeatureOption">
    <xs:list>
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:enumeration value="F0"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="F0A"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="F0B"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="F0C"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="F1"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="F2"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="F2A"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="F3"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="F3A"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="F3B"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="F3C"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="DataOnly"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:list>
</xs:simpleType>
```

using in this way

```
<xs:element name="Feature" type="FeatureOptionType" />
```